# Are apprentice homework hours counted in working hours in France?

Tags: education, france, legal-education

The article L6222-24 of the French Working Code says that:

> The time devoted by the apprentice to the training provided in apprenticeship training centers is included in the work schedule

Does that mean that homework hours must be included as part of my working hours?

Comment: Not sure how you imagine this working in practice. A more plausible question is whether apprentice are allowed to do their homework while on the clock (which pre-Covid 19 would mean present at their workplace).